# Disable eazfuscator json encryption

Tags: c#, json, eazfuscator

When I use eaz and newtonsoft json it encrypts all my json data. Is there a way to decrypt it in c# or disable the encryption of the data?

I use virtualization and encryption with password

Comment: can you show us an example of your code and how youre doing this so that we can help you

Comment: string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
And then write output

Comment: what are you doing with eaz before or after? please edit your question to give a fuller picture

Comment: @SimonPrice ones home surz

Comment: What version of Eazfuscator.NET do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I talked with Eazfuscator back in 2020 and was able to integrate this using the constructor nicely.

One thing you MUST do however is use the json property name attribute as obfuscated properties will get renamed, you can't be sure what name it will get and also can't guarantee that the "next" compilation/ obfuscation generates the same name.

Anyway easy enough to fix method 1 use the names from the json to map via constructor

```
private class MyProprietaryData
{

   
   internal MyProprietaryData(string a1, int a2)
   {
      AccountNumber=a1;
      Code=a2;

   }
   
   [JsonProperty("a1")]
   public string AccountNumber{get;}

   [JsonProperty("a2")]
   public int Code{get;}
}
```

method 2 use json to populate the fields and not the properties

```
private class MyProprietaryData
{
   [JsonProperty("a1")]
   string _accountNumber;

   [JsonProperty("a2")]
   int _code;
   
   internal MyProprietaryData(string accountNumber, int code)
   {
      AccountNumber=accountNumber;
      Code=code;

   }
   
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string AccountNumber  =>_accountNumber;

   [JsonIgnore]
   public int Code => _code;
}
```

As well as all the combinations that .net gives you, only thing you should remember is that field renaming will affect run-time generated mappers like json serialization does. This works on the new .net json as well as the newtonsoft json.

*You didn't ask it but a free piece of advice, when excepting external data like with json, xml, gRPC always assume data is manipulated and validate the data, you can do this by having a checksum field that you serialize  in the data and that you check, in case of json in the [jsonconstructor] annotated constructor.*